# How to move the position text and image in JLabel & JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I am trying to move the position of my image and text which is added by `JLabel` in `JPanel`, but I am not able to move it's position.

```
JLabel label1=new JLabel();
ImageIcon imageIcon1 = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("1.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(80, 80, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
label1.setIcon(imageIcon1);
label1.setText("Do not");       
label1.setFont(new Font("Time New Roman",Font.PLAIN,24));
label1.setForeground(Color.white);
//label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM); 
label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
//label1.setAlignmentX(50);
//label1.setAlignmentY(100);

Border border1=BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white, 5);
JPanel pln1=new JPanel();
pln1.setBackground(new Color(123,50,250));
pln1.setBounds(0, 0, 375, 250);
pln1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pln1.setBorder(border1);
pln1.add(label1);
```

Comment: What layout manager are you using?

Comment: Define "move"? What is happening? What do you expect to see? Code looks reasonable. You are attempting to use Borders to affect the position of the label. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `pln1.setBounds(0, 0, 375, 250);` 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).